# How to select specific value from multiple values returned by prop()?

Tags: jquery

I have this html element:

```
<select name="category" class="form form-control brand_name product_cat">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
</select>
```

As you can see there are several class names assigned. Using the jQuery `prop()` method, how can I only get the class name at the end or beginning ? Or is there any other method to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Split it using space then get the desired class based on index

```js
var sltcls = $("select").attr("class").split(" ");


console.log("first class : "+sltcls[0])
console.log("last class : "+sltcls[sltcls.length-1])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="category" class="form form-control brand_name product_cat">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. That was an easy hack !
There isn't any predefined method to do so, is there ?

Comment: @RabinLama nothing i am aware of .

Answer (score 0):

You can get all class using `attr('class')` than split the string on space. Then you can access the it as an array.

```js
var classList = $('select').attr('class').split(' ');
console.log('First class in select : ' + classList[0]);
console.log('Last class in select : ' + classList[classList.length - 1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="category" class="form form-control brand_name product_cat">
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i dont see any difference in my answer and this one. why bother answering if it is already there.

Comment: Well, my bad, my code snippet was open. All the answer on this thread are same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementByName('category').className.split(/\s+/);` to get you an array of class names. Then you can get the fisrt and last class names by the following way

```
var allClassList = document.getElementByName('category').className.split(/\s+/);

var fist_class_name = allClassList[0] ;
var last_class_name = allClassList[allClassList.length-1] ;
```